# PHP Replace each letter from words

Tags: php, function

I need a function to replace each letter from a word with other letters. For example:

```
a = tu
b = mo
c = jo
```

If I write "abc", I want to get "tumoji", if I write "bca" I want to get "mojotu", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$from = array('a',
              'b', 
              'c'
             );
$to = array('tu',
            'mo', 
            'jo'
           );
$original = 'cab';
$new = strtr($original,$from,$to);
```

or

```
$replacements = array('a' => 'tu',
                      'b' => 'mo', 
                      'c' => 'jo'
                     );
$original = 'cab';
$new = strtr($original,$replacements);
```

or

```
$replacements = array('a' => 'tu',
                      'b' => 'mo', 
                      'c' => 'jo'
                     );
$original = 'cab';
$new = '';
foreach(str_split($original) as $letter) {
    $new .= $replacements[$letter];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is correct use of `strtr()` in your first example?

Comment: Should you be passing `array_combine($from, $to)` ?

Comment: @alex - both from/to and replacements are valid syntax, and certainly a from/to set of arrays could be combined to give a replacements array... probably best to define as an associative replacements array in the first place though

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

```
$str = strtr($str, array('a' => 'tu' /*, ... */));
```